# Why does adding a view::filter trigger multiple redundant sentinel checks?

Tags: c++, sentinel, range-v3

Given `str` is a string

```
auto str = std::string{};
getline(std::cin, str);
```

I notice when we have a `view::filter` exist on a lazy range, there will be many redundant sentinel checks even with -O3. CE [godbolt.org/g/B3ZGbm](https://godbolt.org/g/B3ZGbm)

```
for (auto sv : str | ranges::view::delimit('#')
                   // (1) pointer check and delimit check here
                   | ranges::view::filter(onlyalpha)
                   // (2) pointer check and delimit check here also!
                   | ranges::view::transform(to_ints) ) {
    std::cout << sv;
    // (3) pointer check and delimit check here too!
}
```

However, if I try to embed that filter into transform like this

```
auto to_ints_with_filter = [](unsigned char ch){
    if (std::isalpha(ch)) {
        auto index = (ch - 1) & 0b0001'1111; 
        static constexpr auto table = 
            std::array<char,27> {
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            };
        return std::string_view(&table[index],1);
    }
    else
        return std::string_view();
};
```

The redundant sentinel checks all are gone. CE [godbolt.org/g/4sMYhM](https://godbolt.org/g/4sMYhM)

```
for (auto sv : str | ranges::view::delimit('#')
                   | ranges::view::transform(to_ints_with_filter ) ) {
    std::cout << sv;
}
```

---

Why can't the optimizer get rid of those redundant checks when `view::filter` is present?

Is this considered a literally minuscule overhead of `view::filter`?

---

### Update

Change bad `std::string_view(nullptr)` to `std::string_view()` as *Casey* instructed in the comment.

After add `-DNDEBUG` as *Casey* instructed in the comment. The end of loop checkings are now gone. There are still the extra checkings before entering the transform. CE [godbolt.org/g/YWUPaK](https://godbolt.org/g/YWUPaK)

```
for (auto sv : str | ranges::view::delimit('#')
                   // (1) pointer check and delimit check here
                   | ranges::view::filter(onlyalpha)
                   // (2) pointer check and delimit check here also
                   | ranges::view::transform(to_ints) ) {
    std::cout << sv;
}
```

With `-DNDEBUG`, it yields a lot better but there seems one more redundant lingering still.

---

### Update 2

I try adding another transform. It seems there is *only* set of redundant checks at right after the `view::filter` itself. CE [godbolt.org/g/sSt8qb](https://godbolt.org/g/sSt8qb)

```
for (auto sv : str | ranges::view::delimit('#')
                   // (1) pointer check and delimit check here
                   | ranges::view::filter(onlyalpha)
                   // (2) pointer check and delimit check here also
                   | ranges::view::transform(to_ints)
                   | ranges::view::transform(to_ints2) ) {
    std::cout << sv;
}
```

Comment: `std::string_view(nullptr)` has undefined behavior: you want `std::string_view()`.

Comment: If you're going to analyze the assembly, you likely want to compile with `-DNDEBUG` to turn off debugging checks in range-v3.

Comment: @Casey Thank you for your kind instructions. I fixed it and added some updates. `-DNDEBUG` helps a lot but there are still extra checkings before enter the transform.